# How can I stack views programmatically without manually calculating offsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am programmatically generating 2 menus for a view, one of which will always be shown, and one which *may* be shown - call them `Menu 1` and `Menu 2`. Is there a way to create these such that `Menu 2` will be on the bottom of the containing view, if visible, and `Menu 1` will always be immediately above `Menu 1`, or itself locked to the bottom of the containing view?  To illustrate:

[image: One menu] [image: Two menus]

I am trying to keep it so that displaying on a larger device or re-sizing works as expected, which works fine using autoresize masks for a single menu; not sure how to approach the definition for `Menu 2` if `Menu 1` is visible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableView`

where Title will be the table header and the content will be the cells.And manipulate the click event on the header and make it show or hide with table view animations available

On the other hand you can use one of the customs classes created by some other developers

[search here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)